# How to use String object in the String format class method

Tags: swift

Suppose that I have a `String` object in Swift and I want to use `String format` class method to combine it and several other objects like this:

```
var foo = 0
var str = "str"
String(format: "%d (%s)", foo, str)
```

This example doesn't work as expected because `%s` can't handle `String` objects. How can I do it then?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String(format:)` is bridged to the `-[NSString initWithFormat]` method and accepts
the same format specifiers, such as `%@` for objects. `String` is bridged to
`NSString` automatically, therefore you can use `%@` for Swift strings as well. Also note that the Swift `Int` type corresponds to `long` in C:

```
var foo = 0
var str = "str"
let result = String(format: "%ld (%@)", foo, str)
```

Answer (score 1):

you just use string interpolation

```
var foo = 0
var str = "str"
String(format: "%d (\(str))", foo)
```

Comment: This will *crash* if the string contains anything that would be interpreted as a format, e.g. with `str = "str%d"`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a reason you need the Foundation method for String creation, you can use "string interpolation". For instance:

```
let str = "I am \(height.feet) feet \(height.inches) inches tall."
```

Produces: "I am 6 feet 5 inches tall." Using string interpolation you can insert your variables inline and not have to mess with C-esque placeholders in a format statement.