# How to defer string interpolation in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have got a utility method that creates Url from a config. The config holds the urls with placeholders that needs to be replaced in runtime. Since string format doesn't work properly for `%s`, I was thinking of deferred interpolation where I should be able to construct the string only when the object is available.

For example if I have a string:

```
var str = http://localhost/entitylist/\(obj.key2)/entity/\(obj.key1)
```

I want to do something like `method1(str, obj)` which should give me the interpolated value .

No doubt I can achieve it with `str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`, still I wanted to know if there is any better way of doing it

Comment: The question is unclear. Please provide actual input and desired output.

Comment: `var str = "http://localhost/entitylist/%s/entity/%s"

var output = String(format: str, arguments: ["foo", "bar"])`  the output is "http://localhost/entitylist//entity/"

Comment: For Swift strings use `%@` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171178/how-to-use-string-object-in-the-string-format-class-method.

Comment: `var str = "http://localhost/entitylist/%s/entity/%s" var output = String(format: str, arguments: ["foo", "bar"])` But that is not the way to construct a URL. There are NSString / NSURL methods for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by Martin R, using `%@` is the right way of doing it

```
var str = "http://localhost/entitylist/%@/entity/%@"

String(format: str, arguments: ["foo", "bar"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not misuse a format string as you are doing. There are NSString and NSURL and related methods for forming a URL properly:

```
let url = NSURLComponents()
url.scheme = "http"
url.host = "localhost"
var path : NSString = "/"
path = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("entitylist")
path = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("foo")
path = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("entity")
path = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("bar")
url.path = path as String
url.URL // http://localhost/entitylist/foo/entity/bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Deferring interpolation can be done by using a closure.  You need to create the placeholder storage before you create the closure, but you can assign the values later.

```
struct Obj {
    var key1: String
    var key2: String
}

var obj = Obj(key1: "", key2: "")  // create the placeholder

let str = { "http://localhost/entitylist/\(obj.key2)/entity/\(obj.key1)" }

// assign values

obj.key1 = "bar"
obj.key2 = "foo"

print(str())  // http://localhost/entitylist/foo/entity/bar
```